# Enforce subscript with same compactness with different letter/glyph heights

Tags: letterspacing

I have the following:

```tex
The sentence goes like $A_{\mathrm{row}}^\beta$ and $A_{\mathrm{col}}^\beta$, bloop!
```

And the result looks like this:

[image: result]

Because `col` has the letter `l`, the subscript gets some additional space. However, this is not needed in many cases. How can I enforce that the `col`-variant does not get extra space in the subscript?
Ideally, the same box dimensions are used as the `row`-variant, where I allow overflow on the top of the box.

I have attempted adding a parbox of height `\heightof{\ensuremath{\mathrm{row}}}`, but this is not aware that it is in a subscript, and will use the default size.

Comment: `_{\smash{\mathrm{col}}`

Comment: Sometimes life is so easy. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can hide the vertical size with `{\smash{\mathrm{col}}`